# Отладка android rest клиента

Tags: android, rest, отладка

Что бы отлаживать мой Rest сервис я посылаю запросы на адрес типа `localhost:8080/test1/rest/flight/test`, но если мой клиент работает на андроид устройстве а сам сервис работает на другом, и я не имею ни своего сайта ни даже статического ip адреса, как мне отлаживать мой клиент?

Comment: На андроид устройстве интернет через wifi или симкарту?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отлаживать запросы с устройства на локальный комп, нужно использовать адрес 10.0.2.2, т.е. вместо

```
localhost:8080/test1/rest/flight/test
```

отсылать запросы на

```
10.0.2.2:8080/test1/rest/flight/test
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: этот способ применим если я отлаживаю в эмуляторе если я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Jungle да, в эмуляторе точно.

Comment: @Jungle Насчет реального устройства, если оно по  юсб к компу подлючено - не помню, проверьте

Comment: спасибо большое дельный совет

Answer (score 0):

localhost:8080/test1/rest/flight/test - это и есть ваш сайт и ip адрес (localhost:8080).
Отлаживаете свое приложение на этом адресе, а потом уже размещаете свой серверный код в интернете. Есть бесплатные хостинги - их не стоит использовать для серьезной работы. Купить хостинг с нужной поддержкой стоит совсем не дорого.

Comment: то есть на  других устройствах я не могу отлаживать клиента пока не опубликую мой сервис в интернете?

Comment: Сможете на тех устройствах которые подключены к роутеру

Comment: @Oceinic вообще если на устройстве запущена программа и в ней происходит обращение на localhost, то устройство само к себе запрос шлет. Это если вы на устройстве сервак поднимете и будете к нему запросы слать - тогда ок. И то может быть порт нужно будет открыть.